# Vertical or horizontal rule in Vaadin Flow

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, horizontal-line

I want to section off one area of a layout from another visually in my Vaadin Flow layout using the Java API.

I want something like the [`hr` horizontal rule](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hr.asp) found in HTML. I would also want the equivalent, a vertical rule (which was never defined in HTML).

Is there some easy way to have a visual indicator of a thematic shift between parts of a layout?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## `Hr` class

For an `<hr>` there is the [`Hr`](https://vaadin.com/api/platform/12.0.3/com/vaadin/flow/component/html/Hr.html) class.

`verticalLayout.add(new Span("First"), new Hr(), new Span("Second"));`

## Roll-your-own

Another option is to create classes for the dividers, there are a few different ways of doing this, here's an example

```
public class Divider extends Span {

    public Divider() {
        getStyle().set("background-color", "blue");
        getStyle().set("flex", "0 0 2px");
        getStyle().set("align-self", "stretch");
    }
}
```

And used as such

```
horizontalLayout.add(new Span("First"), new Divider(), new Span("Second"));
```

Using `align-self` and `flex` will only work in flex layouts, which includes `HorizontalLayout` and `VerticalLayout`. The beauty of this approach is that the same class will work in both. The `flex: 0 0 2px` tells it to be 2 pixels wide in the direction of the container, and not grow or shrink. The `align-self: stretch` will tell it to take the full size of the container in the perpendicular direction.

Comment: Seems like a good solution. Can you make it fancy by tapering or fading the line on each end, for something like the effect seen in [this gradient borders page](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/)?

Comment: cool custom Divider class, I like how it works both as vertical and horizontal Divider! @BasilBourque [yes it's possible](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYDNAZMTV3LT), by setting *`background-image`* to a linear-gradient at 135 or -45 degree, instead of setting the background-color as done in this answer or styling the border as done in your link. I tested it in Vaadin application, works perfectly. I will use this Divider for sure!

Comment: @Cashbee Can you post an example of your approach as another Answer?

Comment: @BasilBourque, could you please advice how to add some text in front of that divider? I want to have a kind of from separator: section name + divider. Thanks in davance.

Comment: @VadimLotarev Have you tried the horizontal layout code shown in the Answer?

Comment: @BasilBourque, yes I did. Vertical divider is show in this case but I need horizontal one ... Horizontal line is displayed in case of VerticalLayout but text is shown on the top of devider but not in front of.

Answer (score 3):

I write this answer as follow-up to my comment on Tazavoo's answer, which is great! I love their custom Divider class, and it has been asked whether this divider can be customized/styled further, something like it is done in [this gradient borders page](https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/).

Of course this divider can be styled further! But the difference between the divider and the elements in the link is that in the link, the *borders* of an element is styled, while we need to style the actual element itself here.

CSS attribute in the linked page: `border-image`. CSS attribute for the Divider `background-image`.

(I am not familiar enough with CSS -webkit attrributes, so I don't know if you need more than just `background-image` for a good visualisation in all browsers)

---

The linked page makes the linear-gradient go in the direction `to bottom`. We could use that too, but then using the Divider horizontally would look different than using it vertically. That is why we need to set the direction to a diagonal, so both usages of the divider have a similar gradient. [See proof of concept in w3schools' TryIt Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FYDNAZMTV3LT)

Here is how I set up the Divider class with a gradient:

```
public class Divider extends Span {
    public Divider(){
        getStyle().set("background-image", "linear-gradient(135deg, #777 , rgba(0, 0, 0, 0))");
        getStyle().set("flex", "0 0 2px");
        getStyle().set("align-self", "stretch");
    }
}
```

To customize the `linear gradient` even more, please see the [docs on w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/func_linear-gradient.asp)
<sub>All the credits of the divider class go to @Tazavoo. Please go upvote their answer</sub>